# Optimizely Experiment on Secure Page / Onepage Checkout

Tags: magento, optimizely

Recently I've been trying to run an experiment on my onepage checkout with optimizely (secure page) and I can't seem to get it to load my cookie data.

I followed optimizely's guide to make session specific information load but have had no luck.

- Open your site in a browser tab and navigate to the page you wish to edit. This may entail logging in, adding an item to your cart, or completing a portion of a form. Take the exact steps that get you to the page into the form you want to edit.
- Next, open Optimizely in an adjacent tab within the same browser and create an experiment using the URL of the page you’d like to test.
- Why? The editor will load the page as it would appear if you went directly to the URL in another tab; once you can repeatedly load the page into a separate tab, then Optimizely should be able to load the page within the editor.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably forgotten to allow the Javascript to be run, certainly in Chrome you have to click the little silver shield in the browser address bar to enable Optimizely to load in from the other browser tab;

[image]